# Click on collection view cell inside a table view cell in tvos application

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I have got a collection view cell inside a tableview cell for tvos application. Unable to get horizontal scroll and click on my collection view cell. How to get click in collection view cell inside a tableview cell? I wanted to scroll table view vertically as a parent view and collection view in horizontal scrolling as a child view.

Answer (score 1):

In your `UITableViewDelegate` implement [**tableView(_:canFocusRowAt:)**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614973-tableview):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at some properties for your `UICollectionView` and its subviews: `userInteractionEnabled`, `isEnabled`.

If you can't reach to your element for action (for example `UIButton`), you need to scroll to the element. Check next properties of your `UICollectionView` : `userInteractionEnabled`, `scrollEnabled`, `bounces` and `alwaysBounceVertical`.

Comment: Those 4 properties is already there. I'm getting click only on tableview cell ,but not in collection view cell . When I try to scroll it's getting call on  tableview delegate  properties like did select method but  not in collection view cell or its delegate function.

Comment: try to set `userInteractionEnabled = false` in _collection view cell_